# node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak")' has no construct signatures

Tags: constructor, keycloak, signature

I want to creat an application with angular using keycloak to authenticat users
when i use the keycloak constructor they told that he doesn't exist . if you have any idea just save me please

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Look at your import there is something wrong.

import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';